# Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25'

Tags: android

I have Android Studio 2.2. I am trying to open a project, but I get the error "Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25'". Below the error message I see a link "Install missing platform(s) and sync project". If I click this link, I get another error, which says

> "The following packages are not available: - Package id
> platforms;android-25".

In the Android SDK tool, I can see "Android 7.0" (API level 24) already installed. On checking the details about Android verisons and its API levels, I found that Android Nougat has API levels 24-25. I would like to know how I can update the SDK from API24 to 25?

Comment: If you can not find SDK for API level 25 on the SDK manager, you can set API level 24 to compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion and targetSdkVersion or Update Android Studio 2.2.2 now.

Comment: Update Android Studio to 2.2.3

Comment: i wonder why it force user to update it? meanwhile the production code itself not everyone use the latest version....

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You don't need to update anything. Just download the SDK for API 25 from Android SDK Manager or by launching Android standalone SDK manager. The error is for missing platform and not for missing tool.[image: Android SDK Manager Android Studio 2.2.2]

Comment: I understand that I can download API 25 through SDK manager, but the SDK manager doesn't show API 25. I do not see API 25 being listed in the SDK manager, neither it is allowing me to choose new API.

Comment: I faced the same issue in ubuntu. how do i install using command line?

Comment: Please Refer(ex for platform 25 is given) : [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html)

Comment: In Android Studio 2.3 "Launch Standalone SDK Manager" link was removed. And I couldn't instal 25 through Android SDK Manager. What should I do?

Comment: You can install using command line. link is given in above comment

Comment: how can i change android to use other API level instead of 25.

Comment: you need to mention it in build.gradle

Comment: @AnujaKothekar What if I have android API 25 installed, but still get the same error?

Comment: Check sdk path added for your studio and check if api 25 is present in platforms folder. Try to clear cache and reopen it. That should solve the problem, if api 25 is installed properly, otherwise try reinstalling it.

Comment: You might try clicking the "Show Package Details" in the bottom right hand corner of the screenshot from above. It will give further info on the API version number.

Comment: This is probably obvious to most people but the "25" in `Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25'` refers to the **API Level**, not the "Android 2.x (Blah)" package version name. This stumped me for a while.

Answer (score 29):

Well, I was suffering with this Issue but finally I found the solution.

Problem Starts Here:
["Install missing platform(s) and sync project" (link) doesn't work & gradle sync failed]

Problem Source: Just check out the `app -> src-build.gradle` and you will find the parameters

1. `compileSdkVersion 25`
2. `buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"`
3. `targetSdkVersion 25`

**Note:** You might find these parameters with different values e.g 
`compileSdkVersion 23` etc.

These above parameters in `build.gradle` creates error because their values are not compatible with your current SDK version.

The solution to This error is simple, just open a new project in your Android Studio, In that new project `goto app -> src-build.gradle`.

In `build.gradle` file of new project find these parameters:

[image]

In my case these are:

```
compileSdkVersion "26"    
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
targetSdkVersion 26
```

Now copy these parameters from your new project `build.gradle` file and post them in the same file of the other project(having Error).

Comment: If a problem persists, try to find if there are other `build.gradle` files exist. Also you can find `25` in search (Ctrl + Shift + F, show whole words).

Answer (score 4):

I got similar problem

1: I  tried to resolve with the answer which is marked correct above But I was not able to get the system setting which was quit amazing (On MacBook).

Most of the time  such errors & issues comes because of replacing your  grade file with other grade file ,due which gradel does not sync properly and while building the project  issue comes . The issue is bascially related to non syncing for platform tools

Solution a: Go to File and then  to Your project strucutre -modules -app-Properties -build tool version -click on options which is required for your project (if required build tool version not there chose any other). This will sync the grade file and now you can go to gradel and change target version and build tool version as per your requirement .you will prompted to download the required platform tool to sync it , now click on install tool version and let project to build

Solution b: Try Anuja Ans if you can get option of system setting and install platform tool.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your computer is connected to the internet, then click on the link that comes with the error message i.e "install missing platform(s) and sync project". Give it a few seconds especially if your computer has low specs, it will bring up a window called  *SDK Quickfix Installation* and everything is straightforward from there.

Answer (score 2):

I got same exception while running gradle build for my android project.

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to find target with hash string 'android-27'**

This issue related to android SDK version enable for your Android Studio.
Please find the solution of this problem from attached screen.
[image]

Comment: Very clear explanation. This helped me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the SDK standalone by going to installation directory, just right click on the SDK Manager.exe and click on run as Administrator. i hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

the default gradle version 3.3 may have some bugs, I switched to gradle 3.5 and everything got ok

Answer (score 1):

I have got same error for Android-28. In SDK manager - SDK Platform it shows me that Android API 28 is partially installed and no further updates available. so that I updated  **ANDROID-SDK-BUILD-TOOLS** from **SDK Tools** and after restarting project. It will work. This might be helpful for other who faces same issue as I faced.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like that it is only me who are so clumsy, because i have yet to found a solution that my case required.

I am developing a multi-modular project, thus base android module configuration is extracted in single gradle script. All the concrete versions of sdks/libs are also extracted in a script.

A script containing versions looked like this:

```
...

ext.androidVersions = [
    compile_sdk_version     : '27',
    min_sdk_version         : '19',
    target_sdk_version      : '27',
    build_tool_version      : '27.0.3',
    application_id          : 'com.test.test',
]

...
```

Not accustomed to groovy syntax my eye has not spotted that the values for compile, min and target sdks were not integers but STRINGS! Therefore a compiler rightfully complained about not being able to find an sdk a version of which would match HASH STRING '27'.

So the solution would be to make sdk's versions integers:
    ...

```
ext.androidVersions = [
    compile_sdk_version     : 27,
    min_sdk_version         : 19,
    target_sdk_version      : 27,
    build_tool_version      : '27.0.3',
    application_id          : 'com.test.test',
]

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue for android-29. My issue occurred because when AS was unzipping one downloaded SDK I had stopped it. For solving the issue disable gradle offline mode then sync with gradle files. You may need to set proxy and enable it.