# Error:A p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m occurred configuring project ':mobile'. > Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26' in: /home/sandip/Android/Sdk

Tags: android

I am new to android.
I just downloaded and installed android studio.
I  made a new project helloworld.
while building that I get error

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':mobile'.
>   Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26' in: /home/sandip/Android/Sdk

I read the suggestions and concluded that I have to load android sdk-26 api.
So, I need to launch Tools->Android->SDK Manager .
But I do not have Android option under tools

Comment: have you download android sdk-26 version ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457524/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-25)

Comment: I do not know if I downloaded android sdk-26 version. I just installed android studio

Comment: I do not know if I downloaded sdk.I just installed android studio

Answer (score 0):

The cause is that the project was not building. I used SDK Manager (SDK Manager [SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYFKt.png) in the toolbar) to install Android SDK Platform 26 then ran build again.

Check the "Show Package Details" box in SDK Manager to bring up the detailed packages otherwise Platform 26 may not show up. After the build, I ran into another error. Installing SDK Build Tools 26.0.2 finally allowed the project to build.