# How can I create new Android Activities in Android Studio from the project explorer?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, kotlin

How can I see templates for creating new Activities, Fragments, and other Android related files in the 'New' Menu in Android Studio?

[image]

Comment: Fix the Gradle build error first, then see if that clears up your problem.

Comment: That worked. It turns out I just needed to install the proper sdk packages on this computer. I just didn't know the menu was directly connected to the sdk. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because of your project was not configured properly , you have to first resolve you below error

```
failed to find target with hash string 'android-26'
```

May be you have not installed version that are you try to configure with project, before going to create any new activity try to resolve above error

here is reference where you can find relevant solution for your problem

[Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457524/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-25)

try this , i hope this things will help you thanks

Comment: Yes I just needed to click and install the right packages. Thanks!