# Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26' with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I keep having the `Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26'` error while trying the `cordova run android` command.

Although I have a 'android-26' folder in my Android > platforms folder ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofgx5.png)). I saw many issues with that but I still didn't found a solution that works for me.
I have the Build-tools and the API 26 installed (see images from [the Android SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2PzR.png), [Android SDK Manager in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO304.png))

That's the first app I try to build with Cordova.

Here's the full trace :

`Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=D:\Programmes\AndroidStudio
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 3 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 in D:\Programmes\AndroidStudio\licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 (revision: 27.0.3)".
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 (revision: 27.0.3)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 in D:\Programmes\AndroidStudio\build-tools\27.0.3
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 (revision: 27.0.3)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 (revision: 27.0.3)" finished.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 26 in D:\Programmes\AndroidStudio\licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 26 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 26 (revision: 2)".
"Install Android SDK Platform 26 (revision: 2)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Platform 26 in D:\Programmes\AndroidStudio\platforms\android-26
"Install Android SDK Platform 26 (revision: 2)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Platform 26 (revision: 2)" finished.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26' in: D:\Programmes\AndroidStudio
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 7m 14s
(node:8356) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26' in: D:\Programmes\AndroidStudio
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 7m 14s`

Comment: possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457524/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-25/43038951

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But as you can see in the images from the Android SDK Manager, the android-26 seems correctly installed. As I am working with Cordova, I don't have the same "build.gradle" file mentionned in the post. I have a "build.gradle" file in the android folder that set `defaultTargetSdkVersion` and `defaultCompileSdkVersion` to 26.

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved : I had two SDK installed at two different places on my computer. I changed the environnement variable to the other one and now it works.