# Failed to release a library on Jitpack

Tags: android, jitpack

I am not able to release library on jitpack.
Getting following error:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to find target with hash string 'android-27' in: /android
```

My SDK is already updated for API 27. Please have a look [here](https://ptpb.pw/kQhT.png).

Please find complete logs [here](https://jitpack.io/com/github/aliwaris0572/CustomSearch/1.3/build.log).

Source code: [GitHub](https://github.com/aliwaris0572/CustomSearch)

Considering myself a novice, I would like to learn the best practices before making a release. Please help me fix this.

Comment: check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457524/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-25)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I was not having **buildToolsVersion** in my build.gradle.
Adding it fixed the issue.

Hope this helps someone who faces similar situation as mine.