# cant import some libraries in android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to import some libraries like Picasso, etc. but Android Studio shows up with this message.

[image]

here is the build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mypc.urumcafe"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
       'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
    }
  }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I just want to import 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.1'but as you can see in the uploaded image there is "failed to resolve" error.
so how can I fix this? the same story is for Picasso lib.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your build tools version to `27.0.3` and corresponding dependencies to sdk version 27.

here is the updated build.gradle and it is working perfectly.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mypc.urumcafe"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',
            {
                exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
            })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.+'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: ill test it.tnx

Comment: just copy paste the following code in your build.gradle

Comment: it comes up with "failed to find target with hash string 'android-27' in:C\Android\sdk

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457524/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-25

Comment: Click on show package details and download `android SDK platform 27`

Comment: there is nothing to download actully, just shows Android 7.1.1 and its already installed

Answer (score 0):

The newest version of the library is 1.0.2.
Use this and try again:

```
com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

you might be lacking the [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amitshekhar.android/android-networking) (or the [jitpack.io](https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io) for v`1.0.2`) repository:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() 
    }
}
```

Comment: can u tell me more, please?

Comment: @Shayanebrahimzadeh what else to tell? that's all... this goes into the project-level `build.gradle`. once added, you just have to sync and it should fetch both libraries. please accept my answer in case it works out, which I'd assume.

Comment: first it was like this.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        
    }
}
then i changed it to this
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
but now i can see even more errors

Comment: @Shayanebrahimzadeh update my answer; their order might vary, but in general these should be the correct ones.