# With a Cordova Android Project, getting error - Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26'

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

I am getting the following error and I believe I have everything installed for building to target android.  What are steps to resolve this error.  I provided the android studio sdk manager view.

```
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
(node:7005) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: /Users/SomeUser/Documents/workspaceOld/09042018110859/Company/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
> Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26' in: /Users/SomeUser/Library/Android/sdk

-----

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/SomeUser/Documents/workspaceOld/09042018110859/Company/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
```

Current information:

```
SomeUser-MacBook-Pro:Primerica SomeUser$ npm -v
6.4.1
SomeUser-MacBook-Pro:Primerica SomeUser$ node -v
v8.11.1
SomeUser-MacBook-Pro:Primerica SomeUser$ cordova -v
8.0.0
```

At the android sdk level, these directories exist:

```
./platforms/android-26
./system-images/android-26
./sources/android-26
```

[image]

What are they looking for here:

Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26' in: /Users/SomeUser/Library/Android/sdk

Comment: where does `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` point at ?

Comment: There is only only one sdk path and it is:  /Users/SomeUser/Library/Android/sdk

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457524/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-25

Comment: I couldn't figure out why cordova wasn't finding version android-26 that was available.  But I did "cordova info" and found that 27 and 28 were available.  So I used version 27 and that worked.  Still don't know why cordova couldn't find that particular version.

Comment: What is your build tools version?

Comment: 27 is necessary for many features and security updates

Answer (score 1):

Find the attached link to configure the cordova in your PC

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h6InPOJrinEJDTYWjpYDefyH-3g9IAQC/view

and make sure that

On SDK Manager, be sure to check the box on "show package descriptions"; then you should also select the "Google APIs" for the version you are willing to install.

Install it and check.

Hope this will help you. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you might have to set the path in the `local.properties` file:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/SomeUser/Library/Android/sdk
```

and set the `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` in the user profile (eg. `~/.bashrc`):

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/SomeUser/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_HOME
```

Comment: There is no ndk-bundle, anything else

Comment: `.bashrc` on windows?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed it) I thought it wouldn't work on Mac

Comment: it does: https://scriptingosx.com/2017/04/about-bash_profile-and-bashrc-on-macos/