# I can't perform a gradle sync because Android Studio can't find Android SDK Platform 29

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, apk

I am trying to have my app target Android SDK version 29. However, even after downloading the Android 9+ SDK and emulator. I get this error messages while trying to sync the gradle or generate a signed APK:

ERROR: Failed to find target with hash string 'android-29' in: C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Possible cause: Build properties not found for package Android SDK Platform 29

8:22 AM Gradle sync failed: Failed to find target with hash string 'android-29' in: C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (3 s 476 ms)

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457524/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-25

Comment: The answer you provided worked out completely thank you.